# intercept STDOUT and stream via akka

Tags: scala, akka

Is it possible to intercept STDOUT of any other process and stream them via akka  streaming?

Thanks

Arun

Comment: Is this a process that you would run from your scala code? For instance, to stream the stdout for `ls` command: 

`val stdout: Source[Message, NotUsed] = Source.fromIterator[Message](() => Process("ls").lineStream.toIterator.map(line => TextMessage.Strict(line)))`

Answer (score 2):

Please don't *immediately* cross post your questions here [and akka-user](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/ue_GZZsed1k), it makes it harder to track answered questions. It's ok to cross post if after a while you did not receive an answer, but please don't do so immediately.

In order to "intercept" stdout in Java you can `setOut` on the `System` object. It takes a PrintWriter, which we are able to create by wrapping an OutputStream "bridge" that Akka Streams provide, here's how:

```
 val is: OutputStream = StreamConverters.asOutputStream()
   .to(Sink.foreach(println)) // your logic pipeline here
   .run()
 System.setOut(new PrintStream(is))
```